# Variable was returned to previous value in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm just one-month experience in perl.
For perl-based program executing problem, the commend variable was returned to previous value.
What is the problem?
Here is the code.

```
1st();
2nd();
sub 1st {
        $cmd = "cat asdf";
}
sub 2nd {
   if ( $code =~ /aa/ ) {
            my $cmd = "$reg $annotation";
            out_log($cmd);
    } else {
            my $cmd = "$reg $annotation";
            out_log($cmd);
    }
    out_log("$cmd");
    open (Work,$cmd);
}
```

In this state, the $cmd was registered in if statement, but executing $cmd after if statement, the $cmd value was returned subroutine 1st's value.
Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Actually, subs cannot start with numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing *lexical* and *package* variables. If your program had `use strict` and `use warnings`, this would be quite obvious.

If you do not declare a variable with [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html), Perl will assume it's a package variable. It will be visible from every part of your program (in the same namespace).

If you declare the variable with `my`, it will be *lexical*. That means that it only exists inside the *scope* it was created in.

```
my $foo = 1;         #
                     #
if ($foo) {       #  #
    my $bar = 2;  #  #
}                 #  # 
                  ^  ^
                  |  | scope that $foo exists in
                  | scope that $bar exists in
```

The same thing is happening here.

You are setting the package variable `$::cmd` (with `::` being the `main` namespace) to `"cat asdf"` inside the `1st` sub. You then call the `2nd` sub, which will go into the `else` branch. In that scope, it will create a new lexical `$cmd`. It's only valid in that part of the program. It is then passed to `out_log()`, which probably prints it. Afterwards, you pass `$::cmd` with the `"cat asdf"` value to `out_log()`. At that point the new `$cmd` does not exist any more.

[image: code with freehand lines]

If you had `use strict` in your program, the program would not work at all, because the default package variable behavior is turned off in that case, so you have to define variables.

In fact you should not operate with package variables at all, but instead pass *arguments* to your functions.

In addition to that, there are a few other things that are not good practice in your program. You should use 3-argument `open` and a lexical filehandle, and also check the return value of `open`.

Names of functions cannot start with numbers, so `1st` and `2nd` are not valid names. It's better to name things after what they do or represent. That makes it easier to read your program later.

A full program might look like that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($code, $reg, $annotation); # these values come from somewhere...

run_cmd( compose_cmd(), $code, $reg, $annotation );

sub compose_cmd {
    return "cat asdf";
}

sub run_cmd {
    my ( $cmd, $code, $reg, $annotation ) = @_;

    if ( $code =~ /aa/ ) {
        my $cmd = "$reg $annotation";
        out_log($cmd);
    }
    else {
        my $cmd = "$reg $annotation";
        out_log($cmd);
    }
    out_log("$cmd");
    open my $fh, '<', $cmd or die $!;

    # do stuff with $fh ...
}

sub out_log {
    print @_;
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. The last out_log was for checking $cmd's value. This form was abbrivated script of total long script for my question. Thank you very much!!